# Eclipse WTP and Maven project producing two artifacts

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-war-plugin, m2e-wtp

I have a maven jar project common_platform that is producing the usual `.jar` file and also a `.war` overlay (using the `maven-assembly-plugin`)

I have another maven project with war packaging, it's including both those artifacts.

Now I want to use `WTP` to deploy the webapp project to `Tomcat`. Unfortunately the common_platform `.war` overlay is not getting processed.

If I go to *Web Deployment Assembly* view I see the project is included twice, but the files do not appear in the deployed webapplication.

[image: Web Deployment Assembly]

I have another (external) overlay with `ExtJs` and it's being unpacked as expected.
I tried adding the package manually to the descriptor, but it's added as a package, not unpacked.

How to make `WTP` unpack the overlay contents?

I'm using `Eclipse Mars` with recent `WTP`, `m2e` and `m2e-wtp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filled a [bug in m2e-wtp](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=481746)

TL;DR:

> Unfortunately m2e-wtp doesn't support workspace projects generating
>   multiple archives.